# How to access the uiserID of the user who initiated a workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

**DUPE:** See link below

I have a SharePoint Designer workflow and I need to send an email to the user who initiated the workflow.  It is set for manual start only so it should always be running in the context fo a particular user.

I cannot see a SharePoint Designer action to let me do this, only to get the user who created the list item or by accessing the 'Modified By' column on the list.  Neother of these is guaranteed to be the user who is calling the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the same question posted before.  It appears to not be possible but the code for a [custom workflow activity can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131238/in-sharepoint-designers-workflow-editor-how-do-i-get-the-workflow-initiators-use)